# Qplot in ggplot2 causes multiple regression lines when a variable is factored

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I do a simple `qplot()` I want one regression line for the plot. How do I tell `stat_smooth` to ignore the factors?

Here's my example code:

```
library("ggplot2")
qplot(y=wt, x=mpg, size=cyl, col=factor(gear), data=mtcars) +
    stat_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x)
```

That gives this image:

[image: A factored smooth line]

When I remove the factor I get the graph that I want (although I can't remove the factor in my real dataset):

```
qplot(y=wt, x=mpg, size=cyl, col=gear, data=mtcars) +
    stat_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x)
```

[image: A proper image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can separate the points (for which you want the groupings by the cycl and gear factors) from the smoother (for which you just want the x and y aesthetics, and nothing else).

```
ggplot( mtcars, aes( y=wt, x=mpg ) ) + 
  geom_point( aes(size=cyl, colour=factor(gear)) ) +
  stat_smooth( method="lm" )
```

Or if you have a lot of geom and want to remove the default aesthetics from just one geom:

```
ggplot( mtcars, aes( y=wt, x=mpg, size=cyl, colour=factor(gear)) ) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", aes(size = NULL, colour = NULL))
```

Comment: Do you by the way have any idea of how to make the legend dot for the gear color bigger when using size=cyle parameter? The dots get really small. I've looked at all the legend.key opts() but I can't find anything useful